# Get only part of computername

Tags: vbscript

I know %computername% is the variable for the computer name and %username% is the variable for user name.  I need to get the computername and then replace the last 3 characters.  Any ideas?  I am not a programmer, so please keep this in mind - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the computer name, you can use the [`ComputerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wck0hkd7(v=vs.84).aspx) property of the [`WScript.Network`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f(v=vs.84).aspx) object:

```
Dim str
str = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
```

To strip the last characters from a string, use the [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k(v=vs.84).aspx) function:

```
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 3)
```

Then you can append the replacement string using the string concatenation operator `&`:

```
str = str & "NEW"
```